# R aggregate() by group using some function (e.g., max) but then project on other column

Tags: r, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

Given a data frame with an ID column, a Value column, and a Date column, I would like to do the following: for each ID (group by ID) return the Date of the row with the highest Value.

```
> df <- data.frame(ID=c(101, 101, 101, 202), Date=c("2013-04-12", "2013-06-21", "2013-07-06", "2013-07-06"), Value=c(3.4, 5.8, 4.2, 2.1))
> df
   ID       Date Value
1 101 2013-04-12   3.4
2 101 2013-06-21   5.8
3 101 2013-07-06   4.2
4 202 2013-07-06   2.1
```

For the above data frame the output should be something like:

```
   ID       Date
1 101 2013-06-21 # because it has highest Value for ID=101 (i.e., 5.8)
2 202 2013-07-06 # bacause it has highest Value for ID=202 (2.1)
```

I know about using aggregate() to get the max Value by ID but how can I return the Date column instead of the actually aggregated max() value?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` way if your dataset is largish:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[ , Date[which.max(Value)], by=ID]
    ID         V1
1: 101 2013-06-21
2: 202 2013-07-06
```

If your data is moderately sized and you do not have too many ID values (> 100 - 500 I guess) then you can do this as well:

```
sapply(X=split(df, df$ID),
       FUN=function (k) k$Date[which.max(k$Value)])
       101        202 
2013-06-21 2013-07-06
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to apply a function to one column indexed by another `tapply` is your best bet.

```
tapply(df[,2],df[,1],max)
```

`tapply` returns a vector or a list, so it sometimes requires some post-processing.

edit: OOPS, misread it.  So you have a column that you want to take the max of, `value`, based on an index, `ID`, but you really want the *date* of the max?

That's a little more complicated, and is probably best solved with `order` and `duplicated`.  The first will sort the data such that the highest value within each user comes first, then `duplicated` can be used to remove the extra observations.

```
ind = order(df$ID,df$Value,decreasing=TRUE)
df = df[ind,]
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
```

It's a little backwards, but I think it'll work

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think this is exactly NOT what I need.
First off, I think you meant tapply(df[,3],df[,1],max) (your version gives a "max not meaningful for factors" error).
Second, I'm not interested in the actual max value. I need the date (column 2) of the max of Value (column 3).
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can find is to use library(sqldf), speaking SQL in R.

```
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf('select * from df group by ID having Value = max(Value)')
    ID     Date    Value
 1 101 2013-06-21   5.8
 2 202 2013-07-06   2.1
```

Installing sqldf in mac is a little bit tricky. Anyway, speaking SQL in R makes things much easier. The following is my procedure:

```
  install.packages("sqldf")
  options(gsubfn.engine = "R")
  packageVersion("gsubfn")
  library(RSQLite.extfuns)
  library(DBI)
  library(RSQLite)
  library(proto)
  library(gsubfn)
  library(sqldf)
```

Comment: It should be good enough to install the standard R distribution on the Mac (which already comes with tcltk) and then do `install.packages("sqldf")` just like any other package.  At one time tcltk did not come with the standard Mac distribution but that has not been the case for some time now.  The main problem that could still occur would be if you did a custom install of R and told it to leave out tcltk.  In that case reinstall the standard version of R.